# Django: Get one to many data

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views, one-to-many

I am currently working on a project in Django where I have to get the information of the routers and the commands data.

The query that I want to apply:

```
Select * From dashboard_routerdata, dashboard_alarmactive Where dashboard_routerdata.id = dashboard_alarmactive.routerID_id
```

The method I've used is time-consuming and i want to reduce time. Can you suggest anything to how to apply this query?

Comment: Please add your Django models and querysets.

Comment: Too little information in your question for full answer. If you have models `dashboard_routerdata` and `dashboard_alarmactive`, you need code by django orm like this `dashboard_routerdata.select_related('dashboard_routerdata_field')`

Comment: @Александр thanks for the support select_related reduced the time.